# How to replace the just end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want a regex that replaces the end of a string if it ends in '.id'. E.g if I have a string called 'password' nothing gets replaced. If I have another string called 'idiot', nothing gets replaced. But, if I have 'email.id' it gets replaced with an empty string.

I made using of loadash's trimEnd but I noticed it was trimming the letter `d` in password and the result was `passwor`.

Comment: show some code.

Comment: _“I made using of loadash's trimEnd but I noticed it was trimming the letter d in password”_ – trim methods do not search for specific character combinations, but for each of the characters individually.

Answer (score 3):

Search with `\.id$` and replace with ''. [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KNO9NE/1/)

Answer (score 3):

simply do with pattern `/\.id$/g` using regex

***Explanation:***

1. `\.id` is match the `.id` in the string
2. `$` is match the position at end of the string

[**`Demo Regex`**](https://regex101.com/r/xVxtTi/2)

```js
console.log('password'.replace(/\.id$/g,""))
console.log('email.id'.replace(/\.id$/g,""))
```

Comment: Will also need to include an escaped dot  `.replace(/\.id$/g,"")`

Comment: Op does mention that "_I want a regex that replaces the end of a string if it ends in '.id'_"

Comment: @Graeme .. oh Thanks .i just missed that.

Comment: no problem, easy to miss with all the ticks around it :)

Answer (score 0):

If the ".id" is static you can use

```
var newstr = str.split('.id').join('');
```

If it is dynamic you can use

```
var newstr = str.substr(0, str.indexOf('.'));
```

Comment: That will pick up any instance of .id within the string so "example.ideal.id" would split at the wrong point